# PHP variable in CSS : Undefined variable

Tags: php, css

I'm following a tutorial to use a PHP variable in a CSS file.

I have the following "style" PHP sheet, `style_header.php`:

```
    <?php
   header('content-type: text/css');
   ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, must-revalidate');
   // etc. 
?>

#headerwrap {
    background: url(assets/img/<?= $pic_array[0] ?>) no-repeat center top;
    ...
    }
```

this file is linked to my main page (index.php) thanks to:

```
    <link href="assets/css/style_header.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

and the PHP variable is defined in load_pictures_content.php, which is included in `index.php` before `style_header.php` is linked:

```
    <?php
// requête sur la BDD
$result2 = mysqli_query($connexion, "SELECT img_name FROM pictures");
//$row =  mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$pic_array = array();
$i=0;
//stockage de chaque igne dans array + recupération de l'élément 0 = contenu
while($dpic = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

    $pic_array[$i] = $dpic[0];
    ++$i;

}
?>
```

I get the following error:

```
    url(assets/img/<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: pic_array in <b>/home/leem4147/emilien-lecoffre.com/assets/css/style_header.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
) no-repeat center top
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to understand PHP execution orders correctly.
Your code is executed as following orders.

1. index.php which includes load_pictures_content, style_header
2. After rendering index.php, style_header.php will be executed because it is specified as a URL for CSS.
   At this time, style_header.php is executed without load_pictures_content, so you must see errors.

Solution.
You need to include codes on load_pictures_content.php in style_header.php

Here is a mockup code.
[Dynamic CSS](https://github.com/swdreams/php-dynamic-css)

Comment: ty for your answer, i tried this (put the load_pictures_content.php code in <?php ... ?> of style_header.php) but it act like the CSS property of style_header.php don't exist :/

Comment: https://github.com/swdreams/php-dynamic-css I made some test files for you. I would think you can get an idea.